# Polymer 2 - Data binding innerHTML

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have child-component inside parent-component. The child-component has a property item-checked with type boolean.

I need to inject the child-component to the parent-component using innerHTML, but that would break the binding.

I have tried using Templatize, but not sure what's wrong. It says: Cannot read property '__templatizeOwner' of null

```
<div id="page"></div>
<paper-toggle-button checked="{{powerChecked}}">
  <font color="white">hide/show</font>
</paper-toggle-button> 

  The toggle execute this code 

this.$.page.innerHTML = "
<child-component name='child-component' id='map' power-checked={{powerChecked}}>
</child-component>"
```

Comment: Could you provide an extract of the code?

Comment: Why inject it with `innerHTML`? Can't you use `let child = document.CreateElement('child-component')` to create it as an object (not string), after that set the property, and inject it into the parent with `parent.appendChild(child)` ?

Comment: @Umbo      `<div id="page"></div><paper-toggle-button checked="{{powerChecked}}"><font color="white">hide/show</font></paper-toggle-button> ` The toggle execute this code `this.$.page.innerHTML = "<child-component name='child-component' id='map' power-checked={{powerChecked}}></child-component>" `

Comment: @mishu append would add to the parent. I would like to replace.

Comment: @YukaFujisaku so you could clear the contents first by doing `parent.innerHTML = '';` and after that inject your content with `parent.appendChild(child);`..

Comment: @mishu it works. Thanks!